# Audio file path not dynamic

Tags: c#, forms, path, soundplayer

I need the audio file to played when the app runs and it does this successfully, the only problem is is when I move the application to a different PC, the sound won't work because the file path doesn't return true any more. How do I fix this?

```
namespace Dewey_Decimal_System
{
    public partial class Dewery_Decimal_System : Form
    {
        private int _ticks;

        public Dewery_Decimal_System()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Second();
            timer1.Start();
            

            SoundPlayer splayer = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\Luke Warren\Desktop\Prog3B\Dewey Decimal 
            System\Media\EntroMusic2.wav");
            splayer.Play();


            panel1.Hide();
            button1.Hide();
            button2.Hide();
            button3.Hide();
            this.Hide();

        }
```

Comment: Did you try to add the music file to your project and set the Copy File property of the music file to Always Copy? Reference the path of the file by getting the location of your application / .exe and when you copy the application, make sure the music file copies with.

Comment: You would do something like this to get the path "Data\ich_will.mp3" inside your application environments folder.

string fileName = "ich_will.mp3";
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Data\", fileName);
In my case it would return the following:

C:\MyProjects\Music\MusicApp\bin\Debug\Data\ich_will.mp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do something like this to get the path "Data\ich_will.mp3" inside your application environments folder.

```cs
string fileName = "ich_will.mp3";
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Data\", fileName);
```

In my case it would return the following:

`C:\MyProjects\Music\MusicApp\bin\Debug\Data\ich_will.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

- Fastest way: Just use `SoundPlayer splayer = new SoundPlayer(@"EntroMusic2.wav");`
  And move file "EntroMusic2.wav" into the same folder with the application exe file.
- Ideal way: Move this file path into a config file instead of hard code it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, the target pc give error for the audio path is in the home pc! I search google no one have a solution all say the same thing "put it resource, make content. embed in resource, output directory and many answers but nothing worked ! it still error shows file missing which point the file path from the home pc.
I was forced to put all audio files in aseperate mapp and send it to the friend and told him to put tha mapp on his pc under C:\GameAudio and changed all the audio in the program to the new location t.ex C:\GameAudio\hit.wav.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Sounds", "SoundForCorrectAnswer.wav");
            SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(path);
            player.Play();
```

("Sounds" is the folder where the sounds are located, in this situation SoundForCorrectAnswer.wav)
Here's the code, but you have to go properties of the sound and try the following steps:

1. Right-click on the sound file in the Solution Explorer and select
   Properties.
2. In the Properties window, set the "Copy to Output Directory"
   property to "Copy always" and for "Build Action" set "Content".
3. Run